# How to install the Avid codec for use in Blender

Tags: rendering

This might sound like a fairly uneducated question, but I'm asking the question because I'm uneducated.  My uncle works in the visual effects industry, and he told me that Avid makes a video codec that has great quality and can even render with an alpha channel.  Does this codec exist (I haven't been able to find it)? If so, how can I install it on a Linux Mint machine for use in Blender?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The later era Avid format is DNxHD, with the more recent DNxHR.

FFMPEG is capable of decoding DNxHD. If using proper libraries, Blender would import DNxHD as an 8 bit per channel image, likely sub-optimal. Blender relies on swscale from FFMPEG to convert the (typically) YCbCr planes to RGB, at 8 bits per channel.

DNxHD is not a reliable format for visual effects, nor is any codec for that matter.

Comment: Once the DNxHD codec is installed on your system, (i don't know if it there are a any linux versions) you can decode images stored in that format and use them directly in blender. I don't think you can write images out though. Using FFMPEG you should have no trouble encoding an image sequence into DNxHD

Comment: Okay, sounds good.  Thanks for the answer!  Do you know of any other video format that can carry an alpha channel?  I understand that this can be accomplished with .png image sequences, but I'm just curious.

Comment: No. QuickTime on OSX permitted a variant, but it is wiser to use a still image format for inter-pipeline work, in particular EXR. Remember that PNG is a janky format due to alpha storage and the nature of this quantization.